# Unit testing lists with CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

First, I would like to let you know that this is part of a homework exercise over Unit Testing.

What I need the test to do: I need to test that the list "actual" is equivalent to the list "expected".

This test fails and I receive this message:

*CreatePurchasableList_IncludesExpectedItems
Source: GrandTotal.UnitTests.cs line 13
Duration: 30 ms
Message:
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent failed. The expected collection contains 1 occurrence(s) of <GrandTotal_exercise.Appointment>. The actual collection contains 0 occurrence(s).
Stack Trace:
ProgramTests.CreatePurchasableList_IncludesExpectedItems() line 51*

**The method we want to test...**

```cs
public static List<IPurchasable> CreatePurchasableList()
{
    var appointment = new Appointment()
    {
        Name = "James",
        StartDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
        EndDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2),
        Price = 100D
    };
    var book = new Book()
    {
        Title = "Welcome to Advanced C#",
        Price = 50D,
        TaxRate = 0.0825D,
        ShippingRate = 5D
     };
     var snack = new Snack()
     {
         Price = 2D
     };
     var tshirt = new TShirt()
     {
         Size = "2X",
         Price = 25D,
         TaxRate = 0.0625D,
         ShippingRate = 2
     };

     var items = new List<IPurchasable>();
     items.Add(appointment);
     items.Add(book);
     items.Add(snack);
     items.Add(tshirt);

     return items;
}
```

**TestMethod...**

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreatePurchasableList_IncludesExpectedItems()
{
    //Arrange
    var appointment = new Appointment()
    {
        Name = "James",
        StartDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
        EndDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2),
        Price = 100D
    };
    var book = new Book()
    {
        Title = "Welcome to Advanced C#",
        Price = 50D,
        TaxRate = 0.0825D,
        ShippingRate = 5D
    };
    var snack = new Snack()
    {
         Price = 2D
    };
    var tshirt = new TShirt()
    {
        Size = "2X",
        Price = 25D,
        TaxRate = 0.0625D,
        ShippingRate = 2
    };
    var expectedList = new List<IPurchasable>();         
    var purchasableListActual = Program.CreatePurchasableList();
            
    //Act
    expectedList.Add(appointment);
    expectedList.Add(book);
    expectedList.Add(snack);
    expectedList.Add(tshirt);
    //Assert
    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expectedList, purchasableListActual);
}
```

To be more clear I want to ensure that both tests include "appointment", "book", "snack", and "t-shirt".

I do not care what is inside of these objects or the order that they are in.

Comment: The lists are not the same. I.e. the reference to a book in one list is not the same as the reference to a book in the other.CollectionAssert:AreEquivalent compares references, if you want to compare deeper you need to do something else.

Comment: @PalleDue So, I need to reference the book that is within the CreatePurchasableList method specifically. Do you know how I could do that? something like this?                                                var appointment = Program.CreatePurchasableList.book;

Comment: Also beware that DateTime.Now will likely return a slightly different tick count, even between lines 6 and 7 of your first snippet. This means that even if collection assert could check value/structural equality that the objects you create in the test would compare unequal due to the two methods creating the DateTimes at slightly different... times. You'll likely have to mock a "time service" (which is likely out of scope here) *or* store the time in a variable or pass it as a parameter to the method

Comment: Separately, it looks like you are using MsTest. I'm not sure if it's possible with that framework, but the xUnit version of that assertion method allows you to provide a custom Equality Comparer. You may need to find a similar overload if one exists

Comment: "_I do not care what is inside of these objects or the order that they are in._" Does this mean you only need to verify the size and types in the lists?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 so would this be a problem even if I'm only testing for equivalency?

Comment: @LennartStoop correct!

Comment: That's a peculiar unit test to write. But in that case you don't want `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` you can't even use `CollectionAssert.Contains` since that checks for reference. You'll likely need to `Assert.NotNull(expectedList.OfType<Book>().SingleOrDefault())` x4 followed by Assert.Equals on the length

Comment: You should override Equals on all your IPurchasable decendants. The would make the CollectionAssert work.